# Como reduzir espaços nas laterais da página usando css e substituir estilos temáticos de observação

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, layout

I'm using a theme called Remark which is very good, but I needed to override the css style to reduce those spaces on the sides of the page (as shown). Does anyone know how to help me?

Project: Asp.net Core MVC.

Thanks :)

[Remark](https://remark-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/javascript/)

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rLHQ.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naR8j.png)

//Page

```
    @model IEnumerable<Retaguarda.Application.ViewModels.Financeiro.FinanceiroListViewModel>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Gerenciar Controle Financeiro";
    //var mensagemObject = TempData["Mensagem"];
}

<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h2 class="panel-title">@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
        <div class="page-header-actions">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home">Home</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active">financeiro-gerenciar/listar-todos</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body container-fluid">
            <table id="dtFinanceiroIndex" class="table-responsive-lg table table-striped table-bordered center-header table-vcenter" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead class="bg-blue-grey-100">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <span class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
                                <input id="dt-financeiro-selectable-all" class="selectable-all" type="checkbox">
                                <label></label>
                            </span>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Tipo de Controle Financeiro
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Número do Documento
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Valor do Documento
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Cliente/Fornecedor
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Ações
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's just using Bootstrap, so read their docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
html {
  margin: 0!important;
  padding: 0!important;
}
```

Or inside the HTML in the head tags, you can do this:

```
<head>
<title>My website :)</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" src="remark.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" src="style.css" />
</head>
```

were your own css file is at the bottom. Inside style.css, you can use the code above, except without the !important part on both lines.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Rayyan, but it didn't work. I believe it is a panel. I've tried everything and it didn't work. 
Look at image 2.

Comment: The problem may be in the page-content ...